# Forcing Google Chrome on OS X quit/terminate after the last tab is closed?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I like having the minimal number of applications open in OS X, because then the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> switcher will not be clogged with "unused" apps. Hence, it'd be nice if I could configure Chrome to close after the last tab has been closed.

It is sub-optimal to remember to use Quit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> "if I'm on the last tab", because there might be another window in the background (which I'd accidentally close), and it's just another thing to remember (closing the current window is an easier decision -- do I need the web page I'm looking at up?).

How can I ensure Chrome is terminated after its last tab and window has been closed?

Answer (score -1):

I wanted the same behaviour and went looking for a plugin that would have this effect.  I couldn't find one that did exactly this, but I did find a few such as [Last Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/last-tab/nggjcpipkefkgldicofgmealjndjnhba?hl=en) which will open a new tab whenever the last tab in a window is closed.  That way you're not left with a windowless instance of Chrome running, and when you do close the last tab you get some feedback that you should switch from Cmd-W to Cmd-Q.